# How to write OpenGL ES on RenderMonkey?

Tags: opengl-es, emulation

what are the steps to download an OpenGL emulator on Rendermonkey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendermonkey is an IDE for writing and testing your shaders,
but if you want to write an OpenGL ES application you have to choose the programming language which you gonna use and the IDE which you are comfortable with.

As for the emulators and setting up everything, I believe this OpenGLES programming Guide book samples wiki will help you out:

http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/wiki/Instructions

Just follow the instructions ;)

Comment: the thing is that i am a college student , and am doing an internship. My task is to research about openGL ES learn to code with it and then try it on android. i found out an that android has a gd aopengl library but they dint like it since they want more tools to draw more complicated stuff like a car or something. i tried out renderMonkey but am not seing how its going to make my life easier, nobody here have a knoweldge in openGL and am lost. what do you advise me to do ? please am completly lost

Comment: i want an IDE that offers gd tools that can ease my life while designing complex object i dont want to do everything from the code.

Comment: You cannot make everything from one IDE, you have to model your 3D objects outside the coding and everything. You gonna need to learn how to use Blender, Maya or 3Ds Max, then once you finish modeling and texturing, you gonna export the object to a file format that your application can handle and draw. After exporting that object, you go back to OpenGL and code how to interact with that object.. 
I hope that this will help =)

Comment: One more thing I forgot to say is that you have really to try working on an Android device directly instead of using emulators. It is easier and faster to learn that way...

Comment: i started learning blender, its pretty cool . i know this may seem to be a dumb question . blender can supports animation and game engine. once my my animation project is done ,i export my file to a .OBJ file and after i import it in android will the animation show on the emulator , and does ur code support it ?